# Testing onChange function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm relatively new to Jest and testing in general. I have a component with an input element:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface inputProps{
    placeholder: string;
    className: string;
    value: string;
    onSearch: (depID: string) => void;
}

onSearch(event: any){
    event.preventDefault();
    //the actual onclick event is in another Component
    this.props.onSearch(event.target.value.trim());
}

export class InputBox extends React.Component<inputProps, searchState> {
  render() {
        return (
            <input
                onChange={this.onSearch} //need to test this
                className={this.props.className} 
                type="text"
                value={this.props.value}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
        );
    }
}
```

I want a test that checks that input element's `onChange` is a function that takes in the input element's `value` attribute as the parameter. This is how far I have gotten so far:

```
//test to see the input element's onchange 
//returns a function that takes its value as a param
it("onChange param is the same value as the input value", () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const input = enzyme.shallow(<InputBox 
                                    value="TestVal"
                                    placeholder="" 
                                    className="" 
                                    onSearch={mockFn}/>);


       input.find('input').simulate('change',  { preventDefault() {} });
       expect(mockFn.mock.calls).toBe("TestVal");
    });
```

I am going off of the first solution here [Simulate a button click in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747397/simulate-a-button-click-in-jest)
And: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Edit: Running the above throws the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to look into [`act`](https://github.com/mrdulin/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md) as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113292/when-to-use-act-in-jest-unit-tests-with-react-dom)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Syntax on your code snippet I think should be:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class InputBox extends React.Component {
  onSearch(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSearch(event.target.value.trim());
  }
  render () { return (<input onChange={this.onSearch.bind(this)} />); }
}
```

The test is failing because, as same you define the `preventDefault` function on the event object, you also must define other properties used on the `onSearch` function.

```
it('should call onChange prop', () => {
  const onSearchMock = jest.fn();
  const event = {
    preventDefault() {},
    target: { value: 'the-value' }
  };
  const component = enzyme.shallow(<InputBox onSearch={onSearchMock} />);
  component.find('input').simulate('change', event);
  expect(onSearchMock).toBeCalledWith('the-value');
});
```

Previous test code needs to define the event shape because you are using shallow rendering. If you want instead to test that the actual input value is being used on your `onSearch` function you need to try a full render with `enzyme.mount`:

```
it('should call onChange prop with input value', () => {
  const onSearchMock = jest.fn();
  const component = enzyme.mount(<InputBox onSearch={onSearchMock} value="custom value" />);
  component.find('input').simulate('change');
  expect(onSearchMock).toBeCalledWith('custom value');
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! @ZeroDarkThirty probably you can learn more stuff playing with this [react-seed](https://github.com/UruIT/react-seed) project.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, what is the significance of using `mount` instead of `shallow` in this case?

Comment: In this particular case, the main difference is that a mounted component will take care events creation for you, allowing to test that actual input value is used when calling the prop function callback (`onSearch`).
In general, `shallow` rendering is used for real unit tests since no children components are rendered. And `mount` render is used for full DOM rendering which is ideal when you want to test the full component lifecycle...
Check Full Rendering API [here](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html)

Comment: my test fails, the received element is a full event object, while I expect just the string of the value... any help would be much appreciated 

Answer (score 8):

For those testing using TypeScript (and borrowing from the answers above), you'll need to perform a type coercion (`as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`) to ensure that the linter can view the signature as being compatible:

React file

```
export class InputBox extends React.Component<inputProps, searchState> {
  onSearch(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>){
    event.preventDefault();
    //the actual onclick event is in another Component
    this.props.onSearch(event.target.value.trim());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.onSearch} //need to test this
        className={this.props.className} 
        type="text"
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
      );
  }
}
```

Test file

```
it('should call onChange prop', () => {
  const onSearchMock = jest.fn();
  const event = {
    target: { value: 'the-value' }
  } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
  const component = enzyme.shallow(<InputBox onSearch={onSearchMock} />);
  component.find('input').simulate('change', event);
  expect(onSearchMock).toBeCalledWith('the-value');
});
```

or alternatively

```
it('should call onChange prop', () => {
  const onSearchMock = jest.fn();
  const event = {
    target: { value: 'the-value' }
  } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
  const component = enzyme.mount<InputBox>(<InputBox onSearch={onSearchMock} />);
  const instance = component.instance();
  instance.onSearch(event);
  expect(onSearchMock).toBeCalledWith('the-value');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the solution.

So, instead of passing in the value inside `InputBox`, we have to pass it inside the second param of `simulate` as shown below. Then we simply check for equality against the first arg of the first call to the `mockFn`. Also, we can get rid of the `event.preventDefault()`;

```
it("onChange param is the same value as the input element's value property", () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    const input = enzyme.shallow(<InputBox 
                                    value=""
                                    placeholder="" 
                                    className="" 
                                    onSearch={mockFn}/>);

    input.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'matched'} });
    expect(mockFn.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('matched');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? I simulate the change event using enzyme and perform a snapshot test.
Component

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';

const Index: FunctionComponent = () => {

  const [val, setVal] = useState('');

  const onInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setVal(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <input type='text' onChange={onInputChange} value={val} />
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Unit Test

```js
describe('Index with enzyme', () => {
  it('Should set value to state when input is changed', () => {
    const container = shallow(<Index />);
    const input = container.find('input');
    input.simulate('change', { preventDefault: jest.fn, target: { value: "foo" } });
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Snapshot

```
exports[`Index with enzyme Should set value to state when input is changed 1`] = `
  <input
    onChange={[Function]}
    type="text"
    value="foo"
  />
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for hours. Plus since I had multiple select fields on one page. What I found is that Textfield solution works differently from Select.test given on docs.

**On the code I defined SelectProps with id. (You can also go with data-testid)**

I could only trigger dropdown by clicking this field.

```js
<TextField
  select
  variant = "outlined"
  value = { input.value || Number(0) }
  onChange = { value => input.onChange(value) }
  error = { Boolean(meta.touched && meta.error) }
  open = { open }
  SelectProps = {
    {
      id: `${input.name}-select`,
      MenuProps: {
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        },
        transformOrigin: {
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        },
        getContentAnchorEl: null
      }
    }
  } 
  { ...props} >

  //yourOptions Goes here

 </TextField>
```

And in my test.

```js
const pickUpAddress = document.getElementById("address-select");

UserEvent.click(pickUpAddress);
UserEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("address-select-option-0"));
```

***Worked like a charm afterwards. Hope this helps.***

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing lwc (salesforce) jest tests you can simulate this by selecting the input and dispatching an event.

```
const changeEvent = new CustomEvent('change', {
        detail: {
            'value': 'bad name'
        }
    });

element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-input').dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```