# When to use act() in jest unit tests with react-dom

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-dom

According to the react unit testing documentation:

> **act()**
>
> To prepare a component for assertions, wrap the code rendering
>   it and performing updates inside an act() call. This makes your test
>   run closer to how React works in the browser.

But the test runs perfectly fine in both cases:

#### Without act()

```
it('Should return some text', () => {
  render(<TestComponent />, container);
  expect(container.textContent).toBe('some text');
});
```

#### With act()

```
it('Should return some text', () => {
  act(() => {
    render(<TestComponent />, container);
  });

  expect(container.textContent).toBe('some text');
})
```

The questions is: **What exactly act() does, and when should someone use it?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) docs:

> When writing UI tests, tasks like rendering, user events, or data fetching can be considered as “units” of interaction with a user interface. React provides a helper called act() that makes sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions

Further reading and examples: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md

Comment: Why this piece of text is not already in the [`act()` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act)?

Comment: Unfortunately the content of the link seems to be outdated. Most examples don't work anymore / work differently now. ( Details: Where the author claim `act` is needed, it's actually not needed. Where the author claims xxx will help, it doesn't)

Comment: @lin-du is there anything in your forked repo that wasn't in the original one? https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md

Comment: Would you say that act() waits for the useEffect to complete itself before applying the expect()?

Answer (score 24):

In simple terms:

`ReactTestUtil`'s `act()` makes sure that anything that might take time - rendering, user events, data fetching - within it is completed before test assertions are run.

```js
act(() => {
    // render components
    });
    // make assertions
```

If you're using a library like React Testing Library, then things like the `render` function are *already* wrapped in `act()`, and you generally will not need to use it explicitly.

Note that React Testing Library does have it's own `act()` function, which is simply a wrapper for `ReactTestUtil`'s `act()`. This may be useful in asynchronous state updates, though other React Testing Library tools like `waitFor` may be better.

Comment: If you have async code inside it you need to add `await act(async () => {`

Comment: It seems await is only required when the handle is async.
The code also contains warnings when not used properly.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom/src/test-utils/ReactTestUtils.js
>
react/blob/29fbf6f62625c4262035f931681c7b7822ca9843/packages/react/index.js#L33
>
react/blob/29fbf6f62625c4262035f931681c7b7822ca9843/packages/react/src/ReactClient.js
>
react/blob/29fbf6f62625c4262035f931681c7b7822ca9843/packages/react/src/ReactAct.js

Answer (score 3):

Basically, act() is used to simulate like react actually works. But if you use render from @testing-library/react, it comes with act() implicitly. You can read more about it in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act).

Answer (score 2):

*I dont have in-depth knowledge on this topic, following are just my personal understandings*

#### in short

- when you call codes like `render()`/ some code that **trigger a state update**, 
  you wrap those codes inside `act()`. 
  **`act()` will make sure all the states are updated to the Dom tree & the `useEffect` are executed, before `act()` is done**
- if there are **async function invocation inside your `useEffect`**, calling `act()` is insufficient. 
  you (also) need to manually **add some timer** to wait for the async operation, eg: `waitFor` / `findBy` after the `act()`
- sometimes, you dont have to use `act()`, you can just use eg: `waitFor` / `findBy`
- in React Testing Library, things like `render` and `fireEvent` are already wrapped in `act`, so dont wrap them again

#### reference

- - <sub>> reactjs - When to use act() in jest unit tests with react-dom - Stack Overflow // @this_post @intro 
    > [When to use act() in jest unit tests with react-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113292/when-to-use-act-in-jest-unit-tests-with-react-dom/68928937#68928937)</sub>
- > React will process all state updates + useEffects before exiting the 'act'

  normally, try to use `findBy()`

  - <sub>> Master React Testing with Jest and React Testing Library - YouTube // @intro @base_knowlres @imp @confirm 
    > https://youtu.be/NLFPvO8_hMQ?t=17749</sub>
- > ```js
  > act(() => {
  >   /* fire events that update state */
  > });
  > /* assert on the output */
  > ```

  - <sub>> Understanding Act function | React Native Testing Library // @intro @imp 
    > https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/understanding-act#act-warnings</sub>
  - <sub>> Test Utilities – React // @intro 
    > https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act</sub>
- - <sub>> How act() works inside react? - DEV Community // @internal-bit 
    > https://dev.to/dmtrkovalenko/how-act-works-inside-react-3hc0</sub>
- > *what they don’t know is that `render` and `fireEvent` are already wrapped in `act`!*

  - <sub>> When should I use act() in react-testing-library? | by FlyingSquirrel | Medium // @note 
    > https://flyingsquirrel.medium.com/when-should-i-use-act-in-react-testing-library-d7dd22a3340e</sub>
- > Specifically: if you wrap those things in `act(() => { ... })`, then instead of enqueuing microtasks, React will instead put those tasks in a special queue that `act` owns, and `act` will execute those tasks before returning.

  > There are other things that are asynchronous because they depend on truly asynchronous APIs, such as [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), and there's no way for React to paper over that; so you can't just use `act` for those, but rather, you need to use `await` to wait for them to complete.

  - <sub>> javascript - Why do I need waitFor or act instead of just using await in react testing? - Stack Overflow // @imp @confirm 
    > [Why do I need waitFor or act instead of just using await in react testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206619/why-do-i-need-waitfor-or-act-instead-of-just-using-await-in-react-testing)</sub>
- > In 16.8.0, we introduced a new testing api `act(...)`. It guarantees 2 things for any code run inside its scope:
  >
  > - any state updates will be executed
  > - any enqueued effects will be executed

  - <sub>> react-act-examples/sync.md at master · threepointone/react-act-examples // @confirm-bit 
    > https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md</sub>
- > #### Asynchronous code[​](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/understanding-act#asynchronous-code)
  >
  > Asynchronous version of `act` also is executed immediately, but the callback is not yet completed because of some asynchronous operations inside.

  > If we test our component in a native way without handling its asynchronous behaviour we will end up with sync act warning:

  > Note that this is not yet the infamous async act warning. It only asks us to wrap our event code with `act` calls. However, this time our immediate state change does not originate from externally triggered events but rather forms an internal part of the component. So how can we apply `act` in such scenario?

  > `await waitFor(() => view.getByText('Count 1'));`

  - <sub>> Understanding Act function | React Native Testing Library @base_knowlres // @imp 
    > https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/understanding-act#asynchronous-act</sub>
- > [ReactAct.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5a1e558df21bd3cafbaea01cc418fa69d14a8cab/packages/react/src/ReactAct.js) is the module of `act()`, it is a bit long, let’s try to break it down.
  >
  > 1. `ReactCurrentActQueue` is very important, we can think of it as something similar to the task queue in Scheduler.
  > 2. when `act(callback)` is called, the callback is called [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5a1e558df21bd3cafbaea01cc418fa69d14a8cab/packages/react/src/ReactAct.js#L38)

  - <sub>> How does act() work internally in React? // @internal-bit 
    > https://jser.dev/react/2022/05/15/how-act-works/</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I have an useState set* function inside useEffect. Thanks for enlightening me!