# Why do I need waitFor or act instead of just using await in react testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing

1. I read that act / waitFor is to wait until the DOM is updated.  I've also read that Render is synchronous.  I assume that I don't need to wrap a Render with act/waitFor as the DOM will always be updated by the time I do a click or a test ?  Is this correct ?
2. Next, I don't understand why I need act / waitFor ?  **Can't I just do a await ?**  For Test A, I use user.click and I saw the online sample code uses await.  It seems to work well on my laptop.

   However in Test B, when I see some sample codes for fireEvent.click, they use waitFor.  I tried using await, it flag me "await has not effect on this type of expression".  But "await waitFor()" works.  Why is this ?

Thanks very much in advance !

```
Test A
it('user.click', async () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Notes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  const checkBox = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
  await user.click(checkBox);
  const prev = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Prev' });
  expect(prev).toBeEnabled();
});

Test B
it('fireEvent.click', async () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Notes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  const checkBox = screen.getByRole('checkbox');
  await fireEvent.click(checkBox);
  const prev = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Prev' });
  expect(prev).toBeEnabled();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried using await, it flag me "await has not effect on this type of expression". But "await waitFor()" works. Why is this ?

`await` is syntactic sugar for attaching callbacks to a promise; the rest of your asynchronous function will continue once the promise has resolved or rejected.

So, for example, it doesn't make sense to write something like `await 3`, because `3` isn't a promise; there isn't anything to wait for. (It's actually legal to write `await 3`, but it doesn't really accomplish anything; you could just write `3`.)

So the reason that `await user.click(...)` and `await waitFor(...)` are both fine, whereas `await fireEvent.click(...)` is not, is that `user.click` and `waitFor` both return promises, whereas `fireEvent.click` does not. `fireEvent.click` just dispatches the event and returns synchronously. (Actually I'm not sure that `user.click` does anything *inherently* asynchronous, either — it doesn't seem to depend on any APIs like `fetch` — but presumably the Testing Library maintainers want to keep their options open in case there comes to be a real need for `user.click` to support something that has to be asynchronous. But `waitFor` genuinely has to be asynchronous no matter what, because its entire purpose is to poll a callback every so often until it succeeds.)

> 1. I read that act / waitFor is to wait until the DOM is updated. I've also read that Render is synchronous. I assume that I don't need to wrap a Render with act/waitFor as the DOM will always be updated by the time I do a click or a test ? Is this correct ?

So, there are two kinds of "asynchronous":

- There are some things, such as applying state updates, that React does asynchronously by queuing up [microtasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide); but that's something that React *chooses* to do, and you can use `act` to work around it. Specifically: if you wrap those things in `act(() => { ... })`, then instead of enqueuing microtasks, React will instead put those tasks in a special queue that `act` owns, and `act` will execute those tasks before returning. So the end result is that the tasks are still asynchronous from the standpoint of your React component (for example, `setState` returns immediately without actually changing anything), but it's now synchronous from the standpoint of your test code (all those updates happen before `act` returns).
- There are other things that are asynchronous because they depend on truly asynchronous APIs, such as [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), and there's no way for React to paper over that; so you can't just use `act` for those, but rather, you need to use `await` to wait for them to complete.
- Sometimes you have both of these at once! If you have something asynchronous that then results in a call to `setState` (which is very common — updating the UI with information fetched asynchronously), then `await` isn't enough, because `setState` (intentionally) doesn't return a promise that you could wait for, it just enqueues some changes behind the scenes. For that case, you need to write `await act(async () => { ... })`. (`act` has special logic to make this work; it detects that the callback returned a promise, and it ensures that all of React's asynchronous logic is executed before its own promise resolves.)

Now that you understand that, this question is simple to answer: you don't need to use `act` with `render`, because `render` actually calls `act` internally for you; and you don't need to use `await` with `render`, because rendering doesn't involve any truly asynchronous APIs. So you can just use `render` directly.

Comment: Thanks very much... I understand now.  Render waits for the DOM to update while fireEvent just return without waiting but the API itself is synchronous.  Then how do I know when I need to use act / waitFor ?  eg.  How do I know user.click API itself is sync/async or it waits for the DOM to update ?  Or I should always assume any interaction with the DOM, I should use act / waitFor ?  Thanks again.

Comment: @EBDS: You know that `user.click` is async (and that you should therefore use `await`) because it's documented to return a promise. \[[link](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience)\] You don't usually *need* to use `act`, because most of the functions already use it internally; but you can safely add `act` anyway. You need to use `waitFor` whenever a component does something asynchronous, such as a network request or a timeout, if you care about the result after that asynchronous thing has happened. It's safe to use `waitFor` even when you don't need it.