# Simulate a button click in react test case

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Hi I have a following code, Which i need to change the window location in using button and link.

```
export default class CampaignAdSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.customiseClickable = this.customiseClickable.bind(this);
  }
  customiseClickable(e) {
    this.props.history.push(`/customize/aus`);
  }

  render() {
    let { packages, history, campaignDetails } = this.props;
    return (
     <div className="xs-text-center">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary pkg-adbtn"
            onClick={e => this.customiseClickable(e)}
          >
            Trip
          </button>{' '}
          <b className="color-grey-secondary">
            {' '}
            or,{' '}
            <Link
              to={
                `${
                  history.location.pathname.indexOf('request-callback') > 0
                    ? history.location.pathname.split('request-callback')[0]
                    : history.location.pathname + '/'
                }request-callback` +
                `${history.location.search ? history.location.search : ''}`
              }
              className="tracker-talkbtn"
            >
              Expert
            </Link>
          </b>
        </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Based on my code it has been working. But how can i add the spec for this? i am the beginner for react test. Can you please give some idea about this?

i want to click that button and check whether location has been changed or not?

Answer (score -1):

You can simulate a Button Click for testing reasons with using Jest.

Check out this to find out how:
[Simulate a button click in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747397/simulate-a-button-click-in-jest)

Comment: Hi i can able to trigger the button click but it thrown the following error,

`VM2313:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.history.push is not a function`

while running in browser it's working fine but when i try to check in test case(node) it shows that error. So i can't abel to test

Comment: Nobody said "using enzyme"