# How to call a component's onClick prop for testing purposes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to test some React components (written using TypeScript). My old method was to use Enzyme's `.simulate()` function to simulate a click, but this is being deprecated in favor of using instance prop functions (i.e. just using the component's `onClick()` prop). However, I'm not sure how exactly to call the `onClick()` function directly. Below is my code:

```
// Get the onClick function
const buttonOnClick = wrapper.find('#diffpicker-button').first().props().onClick; 

// buttonOnClick could be a function or undefined, make sure its a function
if (!buttonOnClick) return; 

// Assignment needed here, but to what?
let event: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>;

// How to call it?
buttonOnClick(event);
```

I need to assign my event variable to pass to `buttonOnClick()`, but what should I assign it to? What does an onClick event actually look like? Or, am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Do you really need an event for onClick in your component?
As i see your code should be correct. If you needs an event object then you can pass 
 an object with fields that you use in your handler)

Comment: Also if you provide code of component and full test case(because i didn't see anything wrong) i'll can look deeply)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747397/simulate-a-button-click-in-jest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate a button click in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747397/simulate-a-button-click-in-jest)

Comment: @Boykov When I don't include an event, it gives an error saying that I need one.

Comment: @Yatrix It doesn't quite answer my question because I can't use .simulate(), and when I just try to call the function without providing an event argument it gives an error asking for one.

Comment: @user12894118 so provide one. :)

Comment: @Yatrix I'm not sure how. I need an event of type MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> but I only know how to mock an event of type MouseEvent. And of course with TypeScript, it'll yell at me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onClick` directly using a mock event definition like below:

```
// arrange
const event = {
  preventDefault: jest.fn(),
};

// act
wrapper.find("MobileLink").last().props().onClick(event);

// assert
.
.
.
```

Comment: When I do this, it gives an error: Argument of type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>'.

Comment: You might need to create the mock event as a MouseEvent:

    const mockEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      view: window,
    });