# How to mock a React.MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent> onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Jest to test a React component written in TypeScript. I can't use `.simulate()` because that is being deprecated in favor of just directly calling the component's `onClick()` function prop. Here is my test code:

```
// Get the onClick function
const buttonOnClick = wrapper.find('#diffpicker-button').first().props().onClick;

// Make sure the function is not undefined
if (!buttonOnClick) return;

// Mock event
const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click');
Object.assign(clickEvent, { preventDefault: jest.fn() });

// Call the onClick function
buttonOnClick(clickEvent);
```

However, when I do this I get the error: `Argument of type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>'.` My question is, how do I mock an event of type MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate a button click in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747397/simulate-a-button-click-in-jest)

Comment: @Royal Rat try this approach  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218495/9582313

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React the official recommendation for testing is to use RTL and userEvent. That allows you to do the following...

```
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

const dom = render(<MyComponent {...myProps} />)
await userEvent.click(dom.getByRole('button', {name: 'Go'}))
```

You can mock your click handler with jest.fn() like so...

```
const myHandler = jest.fn()
```

And check it was called with...

```
expect(myHandler).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Or, if you want to check the args...

```
expect(myHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith({some: 'object', or: 'wevs'})
```

Note that if you're code makes Dom changes in a useEffect straight out of the gate you may have to wrap your render in the 'act()' function which can also be imported from `@testing-library/react` e.g.

```
let dom: any
await act(() => {
    dom = render(<MyComponent {...myProps} />)
})
```