# ERROR : expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have following codes, trying to test fireevent onclick but it responds an error. What is the problem?

```
test('fires onClick event', ()=>{     
        const onClick= jest.fn();
        const {getByTestId}=render(<App></App>)        
         fireEvent.click(getByTestId('add-board'));
         expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

})
```

ERROR:

```
  ● fires onClick event

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      43 |         const {getByTestId}=render(<App></App>)        
      44 |          fireEvent.click(getByTestId('add-board'));
    > 45 |          expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                          ^
      46 | 
      47 | })
      48 |     

      at Object.<anonymous>.test (src/App.test.js:45:26)
```

Comment: The `onClick` is not being passed to anything. Why would it be called?

Comment: what do u mean? I didnt understand @evolutionxbox

Comment: `onClick= jest.fn()` assigns a jest mock function to the variable called "onClick". This does not mean all clicks will be listened to. It needs to be given to a component as a prop to be used. Otherwise it will do nothing. --- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747397/simulate-a-button-click-in-jest

Comment: Please include the `App` component.

Comment: @evolutionxbox This  also doent work
```test('fires onClick event', ()=>{    
        const onClick= jest.fn();
        const {getByTestId}=render(<App onClick={onClick}></App>)        
        fireEvent.click(getByTestId('add-board'));       
         expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled(1);
         
})
```

Comment: @ByAS that would only work if App _uses_ the `onClick` prop. If it doesn't then it won't do anything.