# React Enzyme onclick expect "onclick was called!"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, spy

I want to simulate the click on button and expect that onclick was called.

current result fails
//expect(wrapper.instance().onclick().called).to.be.equal(true) FAILED
jsx

```
const DeselectAll = (props: Props) => (
  <div className="deselectall">
    <Button
      className="deselectall--button"
      icon="minus"
      onClick={props.clearItems}
      text={translate("deselectall")}
    />
  </div>
);
```

test

```
function MySpy() {
  this.calls = 0;
}

  MySpy.prototype.fn = function () {
    return () => this.calls++;
  }

  When(/^Deselect all button is clicked$/, function () {
       const mySpy = new MySpy();
    const mockCallBack = mySpy.fn();

    const button =     const mySpy = new MySpy();
    const mockCallBack = mySpy.fn();

    const button = React.createElement(componentName, { onClick: 
                                                            mountCallBack});
    const childBtn = button.find('.whiteboardarea__deselectall--button');
    console.log("deselectall button found ??? ==== " + childBtn.exists());
    button.props.onClick();
    console.log("if it works ==== " + expect(mySpy.calls).to.be.equal(1));
    return true;
  });
```

Comment: Should `wrapper.instance().onclick().called` be `wrapper.instance().onClick().called`?

Comment: @DrewReese i tried but this the result. ERROR: When Deselect all button is clicked: Error: wrapper.instance(...).onClick is not a function

Comment: @DrewReese i guess this is not the way to check.. i am not sure how to check it.

Comment: You could try a mock `clearItems` callback function, simulate clicking the button, and assert the callback was called. Your test is basically testing that `Button` has correctly wired up the `onClick` prop to the underlying DOMNode, but you are trying to test `DeselectAll` component code/logic.

Comment: @DrewReese could you show in code

Comment: Do you want code example in Enzyme (I've not used in a couple years), or would a sample react-testing-library example be sufficient?

Comment: enzyme would be preferred as i didnt get your point..

Comment: and i think my expect (code) is wrong here as i have to check on deselectBtn i guess and not on wrapper itself. But not sure how to check if onclick was called or not in this button

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. Try asserting on the button wrapper being clicked, then if you still need help I can write an answer with what I suggested. Are you using Jest?

Comment: @DrewReese no thats the case.i am not using jest and neither sinon. is there any other way without using that to test it. ?

Comment: Those are the two I would use. Implementation #3 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46211877/8690857) looks somewhat promising if you can't use Jest/Sinon and need to roll your own spy.

Comment: tried to roll my own spy but throws error: Button is not yet there in DOM. so it fails . I have added the code above.

Comment: here Button component inside DeselectAll is never found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your attempt was close. You still need to use Enzyme and mount the `DeselectAll` component under test. Pass the mock callback to the `DeselectAll` component's `clearItems` prop so the button has a callback available.

```
function MySpy() {
  this.calls = 0;
}

MySpy.prototype.fn = function () {
  return () => this.calls++;
}

When(/^Deselect all button is clicked$/, function () {
  const mySpy = new MySpy();
  const mockCallBack = mySpy.fn();

  const wrapper = enzyme.mount(
    <DeselectAll clearItems={mockCallBack}/>
  );

  const deselectBtn = wrapper.find('.deselectall--button').first();

  // Test that the button is truthy
  expect(deselectBtn).to.have.length(1);

  // simulate the click
  deselectBtn.props().onClick();

  // Test the output
  return expect(mySpy.calls).to.be.equal(1);
});
```

If this still isn't working then I suspect the code may not be simulating the click correctly. If this is the case I'll still try to help the best I can, but keep in mind I'm a bit rusty on Enzyme and you seem to have an odd testing setup/configuration.